# Compare the shapefiles attributes with Data model and export mismatched fields like fields, type, length and precision in text file in Python QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, typeerror

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from osgeo import ogr

# Provide the path to the Excel file
excel_file = 'D:/GIS_Data_Model.xlsx'

# Provide the sheet name in the Excel file that contains the shapefile data
sheet_name = 'Warangal_Data_Model'

# Provide the column name in the Excel file that contains the shapefile names
file_name_column = 'FileName'

# Provide the column name in the Excel file that contains the geometry types
geometry_column = 'GeometryType'

# Provide the column name in the Excel file that contains the field names
field_name_column = 'FieldName'
field_type_column = 'Structure'  # New column for field type
field_length_column = 'Length'  # New column for field length
field_precision_column = 'Precision'  # New column for field precision

# Provide the folder path where the shapefiles are located
shapefile_folder = 'D:/Check/'

# Provide the output text file path
output_file = 'D:/Field_Properties_Check.txt'

# Delete the output file if it exists
if os.path.exists(output_file):
    os.remove(output_file)

# Load the Excel data
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name=sheet_name)

# Get the shapefile names from the Excel column
excel_shapefiles = df[file_name_column].tolist()
excel_fields = df[field_name_column].tolist()
excel_types = df[field_type_column].tolist()
excel_lengths = df[field_length_column].tolist()
excel_precision = df[field_precision_column].tolist()

# Initialize dictionaries to store the missing fields
missing_fields = {}
missing_types = {}
missing_lengths = {}
missing_precision = {}

# Iterate over the shapefile names from the Excel column
for shapefile_name in excel_shapefiles:
    shapefile_path = os.path.join(shapefile_folder, shapefile_name + '.shp')

    # Check if the shapefile exists
    if not os.path.exists(shapefile_path):
        continue

    # Open the shapefile
    shapefile = ogr.Open(shapefile_path)

    # Get the layer count
    layer_count = shapefile.GetLayerCount()

    # Iterate over the layers in the shapefile
    for i in range(layer_count):
        layer = shapefile.GetLayer(i)
        layer_name = layer.GetName()

        # Check if the layer name exists in the Excel column
        if layer_name not in excel_shapefiles:
            continue

        # Get the field count
        field_count = layer.GetLayerDefn().GetFieldCount()

        # Get the field names
        field_names = [layer.GetLayerDefn().GetFieldDefn(j).GetName() for j in range(field_count)]

        # Get the field types
        field_types = [layer.GetLayerDefn().GetFieldDefn(j).GetType() for j in range(field_count)]

        # Get the field lengths
        field_lengths = [layer.GetLayerDefn().GetFieldDefn(j).GetWidth() for j in range(field_count)]

        # Get the field precision
        field_precision = [layer.GetLayerDefn().GetFieldDefn(j).GetPrecision() for j in range(field_count)]

        # Get the field names from the Excel column
        excel_fields_filtered = df[(df[file_name_column] == shapefile_name) & (df[field_name_column] == layer_name)][field_name_column].dropna().tolist()
        excel_types_filtered = df[(df[file_name_column] == shapefile_name) & (df[field_name_column] == layer_name)][field_type_column].dropna().tolist()
        excel_lengths_filtered = df[(df[file_name_column] == shapefile_name) & (df[field_name_column] == layer_name)][field_length_column].dropna().tolist()
        excel_precision_filtered = df[(df[file_name_column] == shapefile_name) & (df[field_name_column] == layer_name)][field_precision_column].dropna().tolist()
        
        # Find missing fields
        missing = list(set(field_names) - set(excel_fields_filtered))
        if missing:
            missing_fields[layer_name] = missing

        # Find missing types
        missing = list(set(field_types) - set(excel_types_filtered))
        if missing:
            missing_types[layer_name] = missing

        # Find missing lengths
        missing = list(set(field_lengths) - set(excel_lengths_filtered))
        if missing:
            missing_lengths[layer_name] = missing

        # Find missing precision
        missing = list(set(field_precision) - set(excel_precision_filtered))
        if missing:
            missing_precision[layer_name] = missing

# Export the missing shapefiles and fields to a text file
with open(output_file, 'w') as file:
    file.write('Missing Fields:\n')
    for shapefile, fields in missing_fields.items():
        file.write(shapefile + ':\n')
        for field in fields:
            if field != 'ID':
                file.write(field + '\n')

    file.write('Missing Types:\n')
    for shapefile, types in missing_types.items():
        file.write(shapefile + ':\n')
        for field in types:
            file.write(field + '\n')

    file.write('Missing Lengths:\n')
    for shapefile, lengths in missing_lengths.items():
        file.write(shapefile + ':\n')
        for field in lengths:
            file.write(field + '\n')

    file.write('Missing Precision:\n')
    for shapefile, precision in missing_precision.items():
        file.write(shapefile + ':\n')
        for field in precision:
            file.write(field + '\n')
        file.write('\n')

# Print the missing fields
for layer_name, fields in missing_fields.items():
    missing_fields_str = ", ".join(str(field) for field in fields)
    print(f"Missing fields in layer {layer_name}: {missing_fields_str}")
```

---

Getting Error message given below

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.3\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90, in
> runcode
> exec(code, self.locals)   File "", line 1, in    File "", line 126, in  TypeError: unsupported operand
> type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Answer (score 1):

This is a Python issue, not specifically a GIS one. The error message tells you exactly what you need to know; you're trying to combine an int and a string on line 126, which appears to be the last line in this for loop:

```
file.write('Missing Types:\n')
for shapefile, types in missing_types.items():
    file.write(shapefile + ':\n')
    for field in types:
        file.write(field + '\n')
```

Your 'field' variable is probably an int. You need to cast it to a string.